# Can Simscape Multibody or Simscape Driveline generate automatically the dynamic equations of motion?

Tags: matlab, controls, simulation, simulink, simscape

The description of the Simulink MATLAB package for Simscape Multibody says it can formulate the equations of motion for a mechanical system. I searched everywhere in the documentation and examples and I can't find a single example of how to do this, is there a specific block or does it actually mean the software calculates the equations as a black box and can't be extracted? Additionally, I'm also looking to calculate and simulate the natural frequencies of a planetary gearbox, can this packages also do this?

I'd appreciate any comments and suggestions, thank you!

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/
*"You can model multibody systems using blocks representing bodies, joints, constraints, force elements, and sensors. **Simscape Multibody formulates and solves the equations of motion for the complete mechanical system.** You can import complete CAD assemblies, including all masses, inertias, joints, constraints, and 3D geometry, into your model. An automatically generated 3D animation lets you visualize the system dynamics."*

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. You have to provide something you've tried and errors or the unexpected you're getting. Regards.

Comment: Although the equations are generated to be passed to the solver, these are not visible or accessible by the user. Of course, it may change in the future and MathWorks may decide to offer the possibility of exporting the equations from a model into symbolic form, but for now it's not possible as far as I know..

Answer (score 1):

Simscape Multibody solves the equations of motions under the hood, it does not make them available to the user. It is in effect, a black box.

With regards to vibration analysis, this can be done in the Simscape Driveline package. Though the level of detail might not be high enough to do this for a single planetary gearbox.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called simscape2casadi that, though in alpha stage, claims to be able to do what you want. A description can be found in [this paper](https://limo.libis.be/primo-explore/fulldisplay?docid=LIRIAS1748917&context=L&vid=Lirias&search_scope=Lirias&tab=default_tab&lang=en_US) and the code can be found in [this git repository](https://github.com/jgillis/simscape2casadi). Please note that it requires Simulink Coder to generate C code from your model.